# Is there any way to make the session sticky to one of the AWS EC2 instance out of 4 instances in target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an Application load balancer and have 4 app servers created in single target group. After enabling the session stickiness in front load balancer, request is not routing to single healthy instance; instead it is routing to multiple EC2 instance, which is breaking my application.

Any alternative ideas to have this point to single EC2 instance in the target group rather hopping to any random EC2 instance whenever I try to hit the application URL.

Comment: How are you making the requests? Stick sessions work by setting cookies after the first request. If you are not storing the cookie and passing it back, it won't be sticky.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that initial request should be handled by the instance of  your choice. Then you can use 'Application-Controlled Session Stickiness' to to associate the session with the instance that handled the initial request.

Please read [Configure Sticky Sessions for Your Classic Load Balancer - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application). This might help.

Also if you have 4 servers in target group and want to send request to only 1 server, then you can remove rest of the three servers temporarily and initiate a request. In that case, request will always go to that single server, you wanted. Then you can add back rest of the three servers again. Now you can set the stickiness to associate the session with the session with the first server, you wanted.